# Unable to send email from Amazon SES smtp

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I am trying to setup Amazon SES for the first time, I haven't been able to send an email at any point, I'm several days into this and I'm getting quite desperate, usually, I just put in the SMTP credentials from my web hotel, but now I'm running a Digital Ocean Droplet and have to use Amazon SES, i hope someone can help.

**System**

Ubuntu LAMP stack

**Amazon:**

- Server Name: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
- Port: 25, 465 or 587
- Use Transport Layer Security (TLS): Yes

**Mail From**

mail.mywebsite.com

**Sandbox**

No the account has been upgraded and are out of the sandbox.

**Domain Verification**

[image]

**Email Verification**

The approved verification is my own private email, don't look at that one.
The failure is an email I've tried to register from the domain that is already verified.

[image]

**SMTP**

- Username: *myusername*
- Password: *mypassword*

[image]

**ACCESS KEYS**

- Public: *mypublickey*
- Private: *myprivatekey*

I have tried with phpmailer and the Amazon SES SDK and ive tried to use both the SMTP credentials and my AWS access keys as Username/Password but nothing worked.

```
require_once('mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$email = "example@myemai.com";
$name = "John";

try {
    $mail->IsSMTP(true);
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host= "mail.mywebsite.com"; // Have also tried email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    $mail->Port = "587";
    $mail->Username = 'A332KIA214JSI743NW3NUI7MA'; //ACCESS KEY (NOT REAL)
    $mail->Password = 'nTSNZcBvF34FDGDFP1Y0knGj80wzbhjQDcQomnjfP7O6'; // SECRET KEY (NOT REAL) 



    $mail->setFrom('noreply@mywebsite.com', 'noreply@mywebsite.com');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'My subject - Headline';
    $mail->Body = '<center><p>Hello World</p></center>';

    if ($mail->send()) {
        $getMessages[] = ["success" => "Confirmation sent to " . $reg_email];
    } else {
        $getMessages[] = ["error" => "ERROR -> $mail->ErrorInfo;"];
    }
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

I keep getting this error from PHPMAILER `ERROR -> SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting;`

I have tried to use the Amazon PHP SDK sample from their documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html) but it gives me errors when i try to require the autoloader.

PHP

```
require_once('aws/aws-autoloader.php');
```

**Error**

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/aws/Aws/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/aws/aws-autoloader.php on line 1167
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/aws/Aws/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/aws/aws-autoloader.php on line 1167
```

IF i add the use part i get this error instead

**PHP**

```
require_once('aws/aws-autoloader.php');
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
```

**Error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /var/www/html/pages/register.php on line 130
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

I do not have composer installed.

All I want is to be able to send out emails with PHP when users register through the SES SMTP.

Do I have to register the emails somehow or can I send from any email when the domain is verified?
etc: noreply@mywebsite.com, admin@mywebsite.com, and help@mywebsite.com?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the SMTP credentials, from the SES page and not the IAM credentials? They look similar, but only the ones from the SES page will work.

Comment: I have updated the question,, this is where i get the STMP credentials from

Comment: "I do not have composer installed." You should. It'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: first of all, it will only work with "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" and the PHPmailer isn't working , you should try installing it with composer, it worked for me. No problem with the credentials though. Its a normal PHP problem.

Comment: did you solved it？